# What would happen if the Doctor looked into the heart of the Tardis?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

Why doesn’t the Doctor look into the heart of the Tardis like Rose Tyler did?

Would he be able to live? Would it kill him completely or would it just kill one regeneration? Would he get god-like powers like Rose, or something else?

Also is looking into the time vortex as a young Time Lord the same as looking into the time vortex in the heart of the Tardis? And if so, why don’t they get powers like Rose?

Answer (score 8):

You're (understandably) confusing two different things which were both referred to as a Time Vortex.

The hole in space time which made The Master go crazy is called the [Untempered Schism](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Untempered_Schism), which is described as follows in [The Sound of Drums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_of_Drums):

> a gap in the fabric of reality from which can be seen the whole of the Vortex

The energy inside the TARDIS is [The Heart of the TARDIS](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_of_the_TARDIS) which is the living essence (mind, soul, etc.) of the TARDIS itself. The effects of contact with this aren't very consistent:

- It turns Blon Fel-Fotch Passameer-Day Slitheen into a baby in [Boom Town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boom_Town_%28Doctor_Who%29)
- It infuses Rose with god-like powers of time and space manipulation as you mention

Though this also caused Rose fatal damage, which she was only saved from by The Doctor sacrificing himself to remove the essence from her and place it back into the TARDIS. The fact that this killed The Doctor and caused him to regenerate suggests it would probably be fatal to a single regeneration of a Time Lord too.

Though it's equally possible that the TARDIS intended to punish the Slitheen as she intended to kill the TARDIS. She may have also intended to use Rose to save the day by giving her the powers, but killing her was an unintentional side-effect. These ideas would be backed up by the fact that the TARDIS is sentient (as indicated in [The Doctor's Wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Wife)), and would then lend credence to the idea that the TARDIS may not do anything to a Time Lord who means it no harm (as the TARDIS would know, being able to see all of Time and Space).

Comment: It was implied in "Boom Town" that the TARDIS read the Slitheen's mind (the Doctor said "Maybe the raw energy can translate all sorts of thoughts") and saw a buried wish to erase her past and start over again, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/why-didnt-rose-turn-into-a-baby-girl-when-she-looked-into-the-heart-of-tardis ...so perhaps there *are* no generally-applicable "effects of contact", the TARDIS reads each person's thoughts and needs and makes a kind of decision about what to do, in Rose's case it saw she needed to help the Doctor out of a desperate situation.

Comment: And in those days did Rassilon also posses a [number](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Key_of_Rassilon) of [keys](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Key_of_Rassilon) (and a [sash](http://www.curufea.com/rassilon/A_Rassilon.xml)), and mighty Omega did have many [hands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_of_Omega).

Answer (score 8):

In "Utopia" the Doctor says "if Time Lord did that he would become a God, a vengeful God".

Not very helpful i know but the only time it's been talked about in the official canon to my knowledge

Answer (score -1):

As showed in the episode the doctor does take the power that rose tyler had. He also explained that if a timelord had this power he would truely be a god but as he takes the power every cell in his body slowly starts to die causing regeneration.